# Using a paramater list in python/sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, parameters

I'm using a list to pass into the where clause of a SQL statement in Python. When I execute the code, I get the following error message: Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi. It also repeats my list in the Python Console.

I've search everywhere and changed the code several times and I get the same error message.

Example Code:

```
conx = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://UID:PW@SERVERNAME/DB?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server",echo=False)

customer_exclude_query_sql =  """
select  distinct customer

from customer_table

where 
customer NOT IN ({})
""".format(','.join(('?')*len(customer_exclude_list)))

df = pd.read_sql(sql=customer_exclude_query_sql,con=conx,params=customer_exclude_list)
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error message and traceback.

Comment: Are you using sqlalchemy 1.4?

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS FOR sqlalchemy 1.4.***

Probably easier to just use sqlalchemy's text wrapper function and then bind the params there. [sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text)

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

customer_exclude_query_sql = text("""
select  distinct customer

from customer_table

where 
customer NOT IN :customer_exclude_list
""").bindparams(customer_exclude_list=customer_exclude_list)

df = pd.read_sql(sql=customer_exclude_query_sql,con=conx)
```